# NIFI - best way to handle json at performance level

Tags: json, csv, groovy, apache-nifi

I'm new to using NIFI and I would like t know the best way to make the usecase below.

I read a file containing lines in JSON format (but the content is not a valid JSON), retrieve each line and transform each into CSV format, then write the CSV file
Is there a better way to do this, especially given that the JSON input file is large (3 GB until 24 GB)?

Thanks for your help

I'm new to using NIFI and I would like t know the best way to make the usecase below :

1/ I have a json file with this kind of content :

{"CallDataRecord":{"uMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord":{"callModule":{"mSOriginatingSMSinMSC":{"callingPartyNumber":"AAA","callingSubscriberIMSI":"1234","callingSubscriberIMEI":"1234"}}}}}
{"CallDataRecord":{"uMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord":{"callModule":{"mSOriginatingSMSinMSC":{"callingPartyNumber":"BBB","callingSubscriberIMSI":"5678","callingSubscriberIMEI":"5678"}}}}}
{"CallDataRecord":{"uMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord":{"callModule":{"mSOriginatingSMSinMSC":{"callingPartyNumber":"CCC","callingSubscriberIMSI":"1012","callingSubscriberIMEI":"2345"}}}}}
{"CallDataRecord":{"uMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord":{"callModule":{"mSOriginatingSMSinMSC":{"callingPartyNumber":"DDD","callingSubscriberIMSI":"1315","callingSubscriberIMEI":"8945"}}}}}

As you can see, each line is a json data, but the overall content is not json.
For example, the [ ] is missing to specify that this is a valid json containing a list of CallDataRecords.
This kind of file can be quite voluminous.

2/ I want to read each line like a json data, make some transformation, some conversion and write into a csv file
For example
callingPartyNumber,callingSubscriberIMSI,callingSubscriberIMEI
AAABBB,12341234,555566
AAACCC,12341234,555577
AAADDD,12341234,555588
AAAEEE,12341234,555599
AAAFFF,12341234,555544

First : I tried to use a GetFile Process and after a SplitText or SplitJson and after a ScriptTransformRecord with a groovy script to read each line but I have only the first line and not the other

Second : I tried to use a GetFile Process, and after a SplitText Process, and after a ValidateRecord  Process with a JsonTreeReader (with Infer Schema) and a JsonRecordSetWriter Process (with Inherit Record Schema), and after a ScriptTransformRecord Process with groovy script to read each line, and after a MergeContent Process to merge each line before write the file. This solution works but I find it rather complex for not much, and I wonder if there isn't something simpler.

After the ValidateRecord Process I have the newt content :

[
{"CallDataRecord":{"uMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord":{"callModule":{"mSOriginatingSMSinMSC":{"callingPartyNumber":"AAA","callingSubscriberIMSI":"1234","callingSubscriberIMEI":"1234"}}}}},
{"CallDataRecord":{"uMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord":{"callModule":{"mSOriginatingSMSinMSC":{"callingPartyNumber":"BBB","callingSubscriberIMSI":"5678","callingSubscriberIMEI":"5678"}}}}},
{"CallDataRecord":{"uMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord":{"callModule":{"mSOriginatingSMSinMSC":{"callingPartyNumber":"CCC","callingSubscriberIMSI":"1012","callingSubscriberIMEI":"2345"}}}}},
{"CallDataRecord":{"uMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord":{"callModule":{"mSOriginatingSMSinMSC":{"callingPartyNumber":"DDD","callingSubscriberIMSI":"1315","callingSubscriberIMEI":"8945"}}}}}
]

Here the Process :

[Process used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mersP.png)

Is there a better way to do this, especially given that the JSON input file is large (3 GB until 24 GB)?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `SplitText` and `MergeContent` if you're using record-based processors like `ValidateRecord` and `ScriptedTransformRecord`. You can use `ValidateRecord` with a `JsonTreeReader` and a `JsonRecordSetWriter`, For `ScriptedTransformRecord` you can use a `JsonTreeReader` and a `CSVRecordSetWriter`.

Alternatively you may find converting to CSV first more efficient (if you use the Jackson CSV parser in `CSVReader`). Might be worth a try to use `ValidateRecord` with a `JsonTreeReader` and a `CSVRecordSetWriter`, and in ScriptedTransformRecord use a `CSVReader` and a `CSVRecordSetWriter`.

I believe the JSON reader accepts one-line-per-JSON-object (it doesn't need the `[]`), and it will read one object at a time and write it in CSV. This is much more performant than any processor that reads in the entire file at once since it would use 3GB of memory, or dealing with one object per FlowFile as there is overhead associated with running the processor for each object.

Comment: Thanks a lot mattyb, do you have some examples ? Like tuto for the ValidateRecord with JsonTreeReader and JsonRecordSetWriter without the step SplitText et MergeContent? Unfortunately I have a Json in input, but if I understand it will be more efficient to convert directly in CSV ?

Comment: I'm not sure which is more performant between the JSON and CSV readers/writers. The default property values for the readers and writers should work, if it doesn't put the error here and I can help you configure them.

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm going to try and will let you know if it's ok

Comment: Hi Mattyb, all is right. Thanks a lot